How can I change the stroke width, stroke-color, and opacity of SVG elements in my Leaflet overlay?
I have an SVG layer on top of my Leaflet map and I have created markers circles on this map, and label boxes, and lines that connect them.  I can change most of the attributes of the csv elements, but there are some that I am unable to change.  Specifically, I cannot change the stroke-width, stroke color, or the fill-opacity of these markers (only).
The opacity is stuck at 0.5, the stroke is white, and the stroke-width is 1...no matter what I write.
I create the marker circles like this:
var marker = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "markerNodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(markerNodes)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("r", 6)
  .attr("cx", (d) => d.x)
  .attr("cy", (d) => d.y)       
  .attr("fill", "#445d72")
  .attr("stroke", "#000000")  // => no effect  
  .attr("opacity", 1)         // => no effect  
  .attr("fill-opacity", 1)    // => no effect 
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)    // => no effect 

I give these markers  a "markerNodes" class, so I should also be able to set these attributes via CSS, but that doesn't work either.
.markerNodes {
   fill: #0000ff;
   stroke: #0000ff;
   fill-opacity: 1;
   stroke-width: 5;
}

I can control the fill color normally in either the definition or the CSS.
If I set the opacity or fill-opacity to 0 in the CSS, then they disappear; however either or both to 1 doesn't make them fully opaque.  All other elements are fully opaque when set to 1.
I've tried everything I can think of and could find, what could be preventing me from changing the stroke width, color, and fill-opacity?

Via CSS you can use the !important to force the value. But if the parent element opacity isn't full, it'll always be transparent, so I also recommend checking the parent attributes as well (just to be sure)

A minimal reproducible example would be useful. Assuming that you are using D3 with leaflet and considering the minimal information at hand, your code snippet should work. I was able to use D3 and your code snippet (using the attr method) successfully. Like Giovanni Perillo, I would guess that some other CSS code is overwriting your style.
Please provide more information so we can look into your specific issue.
Meanwhile, here is a working example using the attr method. And here (source code also added below for archiving) is a working example using CSS. Maybe these examples point to something that you have missed.
JavaScript
const map = L.map('map')
  .setView([ 44.65589375, -63.55358325], 14);

map.attributionControl
  .setPrefix('<a href="https://leafletjs.com/">Leaflet</a>');

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '© <a href="http://www.osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

const favorites = [
  { 
    name: 'Two If By Sea Café', 
    category: 'cafe', 
    coordinates: [44.66705, -63.56776],
  },
  { 
    name: 'Sino\'s Bakery', 
    category: 'bakery', 
    coordinates: [44.67237, -63.47984],
  },
  { 
    name: 'Kibo\'s', 
    category: 'restaurant', 
    coordinates: [44.64323, -63.57997],
  },
  { 
    name: 'Truly Tasty', 
    category: 'restaurant', 
    coordinates: [44.64554, -63.59624],
  },
];

const overlay = L.svg().addTo(map); 

const svg = d3
  .select(overlay._container)
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'marker-nodes')
  .join();  // get parent

function draw() {
  
  svg 
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(favorites) 
    .join('circle')  // for each circle do (create or update)
    .attr('r', 8)
    .attr('cx', (d) => map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.coordinates).x)
    .attr('cy', (d) => map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.coordinates).y)
    .attr('class', (d) => d.category);
  
}

draw();

['resize', 'zoom'].forEach(eventName => {
   map.on(eventName, () => draw());
})

CSS
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100vh; width: 100vw;
}

svg g.marker-nodes {
  /* default values */
  --fill: yellow;
  --stroke: black;
  --opacity: 1;
  --fill-opacity: 1;
  --stroke-width: 4;
}

svg g.marker-nodes circle {
  fill: var(--fill);
  stroke: var(--stroke);
  opacity: var(--opacity);
  fill-opacity: var(--fill-opacity);
  stroke-width: var(--stroke-width);
}

svg g.marker-nodes circle.bakery {
  --fill: purple;
  --fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

svg g.marker-nodes circle.restaurant {
  --stroke-width: 2;
}

HTML
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.9.4/leaflet.js">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.9.4/leaflet.css" />

<div id="map"></div>

Result Screenshot




Yes, this clearly shows that what I had SHOULD work.  I thought I had looked everywhere, but it turns out there was a poorly-named CSS style for all "circles" (intended for scatterplot points) that was dominating those attributes.  Eliminating all other possibilities helped me find it.  Thank you.
